# Convert date mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to convert a date field(format: dd-mm-yyyy) to db date format. 
If input date format is equal to `dd-mm-yyyy` format then convert date  to `yyyy-mm-dd` format else return false.

```
function convertToDbDate($date) {
    if($date !="") {
        $result= date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date))); 
        if($result) { 
            return $result; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code? What is a sample input value? Where do you see a returned value?

Comment: function convertToDbDate($date)
        {
           if($date !="")
           {
               $result= date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)));
               if($result)
               {
                   return $result;
               }
               return false;
           }
           
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Please try this  $result= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', '12-31-2016');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php